# Correction for different number of sampling days with individual samples for paired t-test

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I have pre and post-fire data from GPS collars. Unfortunately, not all animals were collared at the same time and none of the animals were collared any more than 25 days before the fire.

For each animal I have created pre and post fire time periods with the same number of days (i.e. if an animal was collared 20 days before, the post-fire data would also span 20 days). An examples test I would be doing would be comparing percentage of time in different habitat types pre and post-fire.

I want to do something like a paired t-test in R between the pre and post-fire data, but I am not sure how to correct for the fact that the different samples will not have the same number of sampling days.